# Unable to see new Active Directory Security Groups in Sharepoint 2010 Audiences

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, active-directory-group

I have a navigation menu that will be using audiences to control visibility of the links on the menu. For simplicity (and to allow help desk to manage the access), we will be using Active Directory security groups to control access to the links.
When trying to add Active Directory security groups to the  link's audience, I am unable to find the new security groups. I can add other security groups that are in the same Active directory OU, just not the new ones.

If I create a new page or site, and go to site permissions, I can add the new groups there, just not under audience.
How do I force SharePoint to rebuild its list of AD Security groups that it displays for audiences?

To be clear we are not using custom defined audiences within SharePoint at all. Under central administration, there is only the All site users audience. The groups I see being populated in the audience field include those that came from AD orginally. I just do not know how to get the new groups to show up.

As a work-around, I could create new pages with redirects for each of the links, and set permissions on the pages themselves, but that seems like a overly complicated and annoying solution for something that should have an easy fix.

Thanks

Comment: To clarify- There is a feature in SharePoint where you can create an audience- this is NOT the audience I am referring to. The audience this post is referring to is the audience that shows up for navigation link targeting. We have not created any audiences in SharePoint, yet older Active Directory security groups show up, and can be targetted- we did not need to create an audience to make them show up. New security groups are not showing up, and can only be referenced by permissions, not by audience targetting.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an old post but I thought I'd still reply. It might help someone.

Just make sure that in AD the security group is marked as "Global" under Group scope. If the group is marked as "Domain local" or "Universal", it will not show in the audience rule.

Hope this helps.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Have you preconfigured audiences in User Profile Service Application?

Try looking this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262169.aspx

Comment: We have no Audiences configured at all- there is only the All site users audience. Since other security groups show up with no audience configured, it seems that there must be a way to make the new ones show up as well.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same challenge I'm facing. Have manually prompted a profile synchronization (incremental and full) in the hope that this would trigger an update, but it doesn't.

New AD groups aren't showing up, and some old ones (it appears, at this point in my studies) aren't being removed. There seems to be a fundamental audience field update failure, while the rest of SharePoint picks up the profile changes just fine.

Found this: http://blog.arjanfraaij.com/2011/05/adding-active-directory-ad-group-to.html

Hope it's useful.

Last edit: It worked. Still had to define audiences to get them applied (couldn't directly apply AD groups), but a simple Audience composed of a single AD group now properly controls audiences. Just make sure you then compile audiences too...